# Twitter share button with JavaScript Quiz

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter

I've got a JavaScript Quiz which produces a result saying the score.

```
test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct</h2>";
    _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
```

I would like to have a Twitter share button which allows the user to tweet the score that the user has got from the quiz.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Do you want a fancy button, link or just a URL?

Comment: show us what you have done! just go to twitter developers page and check their examples. This [link](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/javascript-create) might help you get started

Comment: Are you happy with the below answer? Anything missing? If you are happy with it, accept it by clicking the tick button :).

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Use this URL however you like: `"https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=I got "+correct+" correct out of "+questions.length+" questions on JavaScript Quiz!"` (although you will need JavaScript to create it).
2. Use a simple `<a>` link, like this: `<a class="twitter-share-button" href="#" id="twitter-button">Tweet</a>` and add `document.getElementById("twitter-button").setAttribute("href", "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=I got "+correct+" correct out of "+questions+" questions on JavaScript Quiz!");` to your script.
3. Add the above link, plus this code to your script, to make a fancy button: `!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');`.

Check out this snippet (the button doesn't seem to work in the snippet, but it should work locally and on your website):

```html
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="#" id="twitter-button">Tweet</a>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs'); correct = 5; questions = 10; document.getElementById("twitter-button").setAttribute("href", "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=I got "+correct+" correct out of "+questions+" questions on JavaScript Quiz!");</script>
```

You can generate all the button script [here](https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons/). Also, have a look [here](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/).

Hope this helps! :)